# displaying command output in stdout then save to file with transformation?

Tags: bash

I have a long-running command which outputs periodically. to demonstrate let's assume it is:

```
function my_cmd()
{
for i in {1..9}; do
    echo -n $i
    for j in {1..$i}
        echo -n " "
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done
}
```

the output will be:

```
1 1
2  2
3   3
4    4
5     5
6      6
7       7
8        8
9         9
```

I want to display the command output meanwhile save it to a file at the same time.
this can be done by `my_cmd | tee -a res.txt`.

Now I want to display the output to terminal as-is but save to file with a transformed flavor, say with `sed "s/ //g"`.

so the res.txt becomes:

```
11
22
33
44
66
77
88
99
```

how can I do this transformation on-the-fly without waiting for command exits then read the file again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your original code, `{1..$i}` is an error because sequences can't contain variables. I've replaced it with `seq`. Also, you're missing a `do` and a `done` for the inner for loop.

At any rate, I would use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function my_cmd {
  for i in {1..9}; do
    printf '%d' "$i"
    for j in $(seq 1 $i); do
      printf ' '
    done
    printf '%d\n' "$j"
    sleep 1
  done
}

my_cmd | tee >(tr -d ' ' >> res.txt)
```

Process substitution usually causes bash to create an entry in `/dev/fd` which is fed to the command in question. The contents of the substitution run asynchronously, so it doesn't block the process sending data to it.

Note that the process substitution isn't a REAL file, so the `-a` option for `tee` is meaningless. If you really want to append to your output file, `>>` within the substitution is the way to go.

If you don't like process substitution, another option would be to redirect to alternate file descriptors.  For example, instead of the last line in the script above, you could use:

```
exec 5>&1
my_cmd | tee /dev/fd/5 | tr -d ' ' > res.txt
exec 5>&-
```

This creates a file descriptor, `/dev/fd/5`, which redirects to your *real* stdout, the terminal. It then tells `tee` to write to this, allowing the normal stdout from `tee` to be processed by additional pipe elements before final redirection to your log file.

The method you choose is up to you. I find process substitution clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Something you need to modify in your function. And you may use `tee` in the for loop to print and write file at the same time. The following script may get the result you desire.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="a.txt"
[ -f $filename ] && rm $filename

for i in {1..9}; do
    echo -n $i | tee -a $filename 
    for((j=1;j<=$i;j++)); do
        echo -n " "
    done
    echo $i | tee -a $filename
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of double loop, I would use `printf` and its formatting capability `%Xs` to pad with blank characters.

Moreover I would use double printing (for stdout and your file) rather than using pipe and starting new processes.

So your function could look like this:

```
function my_cmd() {
  for i in {1..9}; do 
    printf "%s %${i}s\n" $i $i
    printf "%s%s\n" $i $i >> res.txt
  done
}
```